# Checking if file was created when using reserved filenames returning positive

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream, stat

I'm trying to check if a file was created. I've purposely used "con" since you can't create a file (or folder) with that name. ofstream is saying it's open without any errors. it does however return -1 for the end pos. While stat also says it exists and is a file. but returns the size of 0. What is the valid way to handle reserved names? I know i can just check the string isn't any of the reserved names too (for any client created filenames) but it does seem like i can just get a simple error somehow, since fstream produces the -1. is there any simpler/less hackish way to check if i can create the file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){
    const char* file = "con"; // reserved

    std::ofstream f(file); // try create file
    std::cout<<"open: "<<f.is_open()<<std::endl; // 1
    std::cout<<"good: "<<f.good()<<std::endl; // 1

    struct stat st; // see what stat says
    std::cout<<"exists: "<<(stat(file,&st)==0)<<std::endl; // 1
    std::cout<<"isFile: "<<S_ISREG(st.st_mode)<<std::endl; // 1
    std::cout<<"size: "<<st.st_size<<std::endl; // 0

    f.seekp(0,f.end); // check file size
    std::cout<<"size: "<<f.tellp()<<std::endl; // -1
}
```

output:

```
open: 1
good: 1
exists: 1
isFile: 1
size: 0
size: -1
```

EDIT:

I just figured out the solution. Take the `o` out of `ofstream`. lol
I realized it will only fail when you try read/write mode.

1. open(O_RDWR)
2. fopen("r+")
3. CreateFile(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE)

If you just try read only or write only it doesn't fail. (weird. what's that all about?)

If anyone's got any more info on all this, it'd be much appreciated.

EDIT 2:

have to use trunc with read/write so it'll create the file:
`std::fstream f("test.txt",std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::trunc);`
`std::ofstream f("test.txt",std::ios::in|std::ios::trunc);`
`std::ifstream f("test.txt",std::ios::out|std::ios::trunc);`

use stat to check if you need to create the file

Answer (score 1):

On Windows (which seems to be the platform you are using), you can use [`GetFileType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletype) to do this.  Open the file with [`CreateFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) first.

On Linux, you can call [`stat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) and look at the `st_rdev` field.

Comment: thanks. i just realized i had to use read/write mode for it to fail. (don't know why that is) i also checked out what `GetFileType` would return, and that works too. when it's a normal file it returns `FILE_TYPE_DISK` if it's "con" it returns `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` (console) but again i didn't need that since opening with `GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE` made it fail to open. a.k.a the `HANDLE` returned from `CreateFile` was `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. i decided to try with `open` (in rw mode), tried same with `fopen`, then with `fstream`, and whala. anyway, thanks again for helping.